# How do I filter the data returned by a map based on the key

Tags: reactjs, firebase, ecmascript-6

I have a react app that uses map to return all the data contained in a firestore document.

```
   const getdata = Object.entries(myData)
    .map(pair => {
        const key = pair[0]
        const value = pair[1]
        return (
            <div className="card z-depth-2">
                <div className="card-content">
                    <div className="thisClass">
                    <h5>{key}</h5>
                    </div>
                    <p>{value}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    })
```

This returns all the properties of the document. I would however like to filter out some of the properties, like the uniqueIdentityNumber so it doesn't render that to the screen. I would like to include a filter that says if the key is uniqueIdentityNumber, don't display that. Anyone know how I can do this? Please assist.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `filter` method and only keep those entries whose key does not match the one you want

```js
const getdata = Object.entries(myData)
  .filter(([key, value]) => key !== 'uniqueIdentityNumber')
  .map(pair => {
    ...
  });
```

and if you want to exclude multiple keys

```js
const getdata = Object.entries(myData)
  .filter(([key, value]) => !['uniqueIdentityNumber', 'otherkey'].includes(key))
  .map(pair => {
    ...
  });
```